# Salesforce - Is it possible to display image file from ContentVersion to custom visualforce page?

Tags: image, upload, salesforce, visualforce, apex-code

I wrote one simple Visualforce page that let user upload an image file then
save the file to `ContentVersion` object.

Now **I want to display the saved image in my custom visualforce page.** Is it even possible?
Looks like `<apex:image>` cannot be used. Also `<img href="{!cv.contentVersion}"...>` had no luck.

The real problem is I did upload the image file successfully but what is the URL to it?
I tested with random URL outside on google and I can display the image (like /../..some.jpg"). But I can't figure out what is the absolute URL for the image file that has been uploaded to contentversion.

NOTE: This is not static resource as my users may upload image to change their user image often.

**Code**

```
public with sharing class ImageUploadTestController {

    public blob file { get; set; }
    public String imageFilePath { get; set; }

    public ContentVersion cv { get; set; }

    public ImageUploadTestController() {
        cv = [select id, versionData, title, pathOnClient FROM ContentVersion limit 1];
    }

    //fill out the inputFile field and press go. This will upload file to the server
    public PageReference go() {
        ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
        v.versionData = file;
        v.title = 'some title';
        v.pathOnClient ='/foo.jpeg';
        insert v;

        return new PageReference('/' + v.id);
    }

    //v.id sample
    //069A00000009Ux3

}//end class
```

**Visualforce page**

```
<apex:page controller="ImageUploadTestController">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:inputFile value="{!file}" />

    <apex:commandbutton action="{!go}" value="go"/>
    </apex:form>

    <!-- none of below works!! :( -->
    <a href="/{!cv.id}">{!cv.title} {!cv.pathOnClient}</a>
    <a href="https://na7.salesforce.com/069A00000009FG4"></a>
    <apex:image value="/069A00000009Ux3" width="220" height="55"/>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe its possible to serve it from content currently The format provided by ScottW works for Documents.

The other option I've done is upload a zip file containing my images to the Static Resources which can then be referenced.

Comment: Yes, saving to the Document Object works. Only drawback is the application then cannot be packaged if document table has records as far as my coworker tried. Wish we could just do it with ease..

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public PageReference getContent(){
    String html = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('html');
    PageReference redirection = null;
    redirection = new PageReference('/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/' + contentVersion.Id);
    redirection.setRedirect(true);
    return redirection;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `<apex:image URL="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!recordId}"/>`

Comment: Nope it didn't work, I put the code below and it does not show up on VP page.<apex:image value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=068A00000009w2QIAQ"/> <br /> I also tried <apex:image value="https://c.na7.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=069A00000009UwyIAE" />

Comment: I guess I have to use Document object instead which is not allowed to have data in packaging phase but it maybe the only way... :(

Comment: If you've got the URL above you can just use a regular HTML img tag to display the image, rather than using apex:image.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, "thegogz"is correct - it is not currently possible to render images directly from Content.  As others have indicated, rendering from Documents and/or Static Resources does work, and IMHO using Documents is preferable because you can access the URL, binary data, etc. programmatically in Apex.

Answer (score 1):

- The image is shown using "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" in  tag by using URL attribute.

Example : `<apex:image URL="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!recordId}"/>`

for more information,
visit [Displaying Images in a Visual Force Page](http://dhawalsaiya-salesforce.blogspot.com/2012/01/displaying-images-in-visual-force-page.html)